# return id in ON DUPLICATE KEY in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, on-duplicate-key

What I actually want is to write following query in JOOQ:

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO `tbl` (`name`, `service_id`, `device_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)", 
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
);
```

I'm not able to find a way to do this in JOOQ. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently (as of jOOQ 3.4-3.6), that's not possible due to a flaw in jOOQ's `INSERT` API:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2123

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. For time being I am using this:

```
Field<Integer> LAST_INSERT_ID = DSL.function("LAST_INSERT_ID", Integer.class, PACKAGE.ID);

dsl.insertInto(PACKAGE)
   .set(dsl.newRecord(PACKAGE, packagePojo))
   .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
   .set(PACKAGE.ID, LAST_INSERT_ID)
   .set(PACKAGE.PTR_JOB, packagePojo.getPtrJob())
   .set(PACKAGE.PACK_NUMBER, packagePojo.getPackNumber())
   .set(PACKAGE.RACK, packagePojo.getRack()
```